# Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, jsoup

I added jsoup library into my android project but I keep getting an error that android studio couldn't resolve all files for configuration.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjw4.png)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation files('C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/GitHub/project1/jsoup-1.11.2.jar')
    implementation files('C:/Users/Aviv/Documents/GitHub/project1/jsoup-1.11.2.jar')
    implementation files('C:/Users/Aviv/Documents/GitHub/project1/gradle/wrapper/jsoup-1.11.2.jar')
    implementation files('jsoup-1.11.2.jar')
}
```

Output on Gradle Console

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform file 'jsoup-1.11.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\project1\jsoup-1.11.2.jar does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'jsoup-1.11.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file C:\Users\Aviv\Documents\GitHub\project1\jsoup-1.11.2.jar does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'jsoup-1.11.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file C:\Users\Aviv\Documents\GitHub\project1\gradle\wrapper\jsoup-1.11.2.jar does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar must be in libs folder and not lying outside in the directory.

1. Create a new folder in you app folder called libs.
2. Place the 'jsoup-1.11.2.jar' inside that libs folder.
3. In your build.gradle change this

   > implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.11.2.jar')

Also note this below line imports all jar files in libs directory as well

> implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')